# Meteor - can't pass variables in subscribe

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm having problems with Meteor's subscribe. My goal is to search through my collection given criteria from user input form and spit back documents that match. My code works when I hard code let's say Meteor.subscribe('byProductAndBrand',1, 2) or whatever number instead of day and month. I tried the same numbers for day and month from the website, and it doesn't return any results. My variables seem to get the values from the html form because they print in the console, but for some reason they don't get passed in subscribe.Any suggestions?

The ScheduleList collection is just a bunch of documents with a certain hour, day, and month.

In the client:

```
Template.myform.events({
    'click #submit' : function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();
        Session.set('day', template.find('#day').value);
        Session.set('month', template.find('#month').value);
        var day = Session.get('day');
        console.log(day);
        var month = Session.get('month');
        console.log(month);
        var instance = Template.instance();
        if(instance.byProductAndBrandHandle != null){
            instance.byProductAndBrandHandle.stop();
        }
        instance.byProductAndBrandHandle = Meteor.subscribe('byProductAndBrand',day, month);
    }
});
```

In the server:

```
Meteor.publish('byProductAndBrand', function(day, month){
    var d = day;
    var m = month;
    return ScheduleList.find({day:d},{month: m});
});
```

Comment: What does your database look like? what are the dates you hardcoded? What does your input code look like?

Comment: Most likely the `template.find('#day').value` output is a string, but the day and month fields in the database are numbers. So you'll need to convert the strings to numbers first. Also `ScheduleList.find({day:d},{month: m})` is not correct, you want `ScheduleList.find({day:d, month: m})`

Comment: Yo, you are awesome, thank you so so much! Added a parseInt and now it works. Such a rookie mistake, sigh...

Answer (score 1):

The query limit in your server publication is incorrect, it should be:

```
ScheduleList.find({day:d, month: m});
```

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, one easy way to debug issues like this is to put a *debugger;* statement in your *Meteor.publish* function and then:

```
$ meteor debug
```

from the console. Then launch the *Node Inspector* in your browser at

```
http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858
```

Then you can validate the parameter parsing and also double check your logic interactively. Sander's answer is correct though.